# Não permitir gravar cadastros duplicados

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema utilizando ASP.Net MVC e Entity Framework.

Como faço para não permitir que dados iguais sejam gravados em uma tabela? Por exemplo, não permitir que o login: x seja cadastrado mais de uma vez.

Answer (score 4):

Por outro lado, com o `EntityFramework 6.1` você pode usar de ***[IndexAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583.aspx#IndexMulti)***.

```cs
public abstract class User
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    [Index("IX_User_Login", IsUnique = true)]
    public string Login { get; set; }
    ....
}
```

Um exemplo para uma chave composta:

```cs
public abstract class User
{
    [Required]
    [Index("IX_User_Empresa", 1, IsUnique = true)]
    public int EmpresaId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    [Index("IX_User_Empresa", 2, IsUnique = true)]
    public string Login { get; set; }
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A sua pergunta ficou muito ampla, você precisa detalhar um pouco mais.
Como por exemplo: **Qual tipo de banco de dados está utilizando?**

O controle dos registros é feito diretamente no banco de dados e você deve tratar essa regra diretamente nele.

O banco de dados têm uma propriedade chamada `PRIMARY KEY`, acredito que já tenha ouvido falar.
Ela faz o controle dos registros não permitindo que você duplique determinado campo, segue link com exemplos em diversas linguagens de banco de dados de como aplicar a `PK`.

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_primarykey.asp

**EXEMPLO:** MySQL / SQL Server / Oracle / MS Access:

```
ALTER TABLE Persons
ADD PRIMARY KEY (CAMPO_A_SER_APLICADO)
```

Comment: Acho que a resposta mais correta é `UNIQUE`. Porque podes ter vários campos com `UNIQUE` e não ser uma chave primária.

Comment: Tem razão, depende da necessidade, é que não ficou claro isso na pergunta também. Se tivesse detalhado melhor talvez não tivesse gerado essa dúvida, mas estou de acordo o unique é melhor para não duplicar!

Answer (score 2):

Você pode fazer de várias maneiras.
A solução do @andervoc, no model é perfeita. Somente adicionaria este comando na base de dados, com isto você estaria tento maior segurança:

```
ALTER TABLE TABELA ADD CONSTRAINT NOMEDATABELA_UK01 UNIQUE (CAMPOS);
```

Exemplo prático:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f10a5/1

Com isto o banco daria o erro:

```
Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'USUARIO_UK01'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.USUARIO'. The duplicate key value is (Maria).: insert into USUARIO values ('Maria')
```

Comment: Acredito que o atributo unique crie esta constraint no banco, pois as definições do entity framework são para criação da base de dados (no caso de codefirst)

Comment: Sim. Mas se no caso ele fazer a base de dados na mão, como eu faço, assim mantenho os nomes como eu gosto, ele tem que fazer isto na mão...Senão o EF faz para ele.

Comment: Não conheço muito de EF mas estava estundando e me deparei com este **[link](http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2014/02/15/ef-6-1-creating-indexes-with-indexattribute/)** que mostra que nas versões mais novas você pode dar o nome para a constraint no atributo

Answer (score 2):

Uma forma de fazer isso, para uma classe `User`, por exemplo, seria colocar o campo `Login` como `Primary Key`.

```cs
public class User 
{
    [Key]
    public string Login { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

O ***EntityFramework*** não tem o atributo `UniqueKey`. Você poderia é criá-lo.

Criar o atributo `UniqueKey` implicaria em criar uma validação para seu ***back-end*** pelo menos e fazer um mecanismo para inserir no banco de dados as ***uniques***.

O Atributo:

```cs
public class UniqueKeyAttribute : Attribute
{ 
    ... // incluir a validação para o back-end
}
```

Criando as ***uniques***, compostas, no banco de dados:

**ATENÇÃO**: Não garanto essa forma de criar ***uniques*** como genérica para todos os bancos de dados.

```cs
public class DatabaseUniqueKeyConfiguration
{
    // Cria as Unique keys no banco de dados
    public static void CreateUniqueKeys(Context context)
    {
        //Fetch all the father class's public properties 
        var masterProperties = typeof(DbContext).GetProperties().Select(x => x.Name).ToList();

        //Percorre cada DBSet<> do DbContext
        foreach (var item in context.GetType().GetProperties().Where(p => masterProperties.IndexOf(p.Name) < 0).Select(x => x))
        {
            //busca o tipo de "T" 
            Type entityType = item.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0];

            // Cria as chaves únicas
            var fields = from f in entityType.GetProperties()
                         where f.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(Domain.Attributes.UniqueKeyAttribute), true).Count() > 0
                         select f.Name;

            var uniqueKeys = "";
            foreach (string s in fields)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(uniqueKeys) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(uniqueKeys))
                    uniqueKeys = s;
                else
                    uniqueKeys += ", " + s;
            }

            var tableName = entityType.Name;
            var attr = System.Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(entityType).SingleOrDefault(x=>x.GetType() == typeof(TableAttribute)) as TableAttribute;
            if (attr != null)
                tableName = attr.Name;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(uniqueKeys) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(uniqueKeys))
                context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("alter table " + tableName + " add unique(" + uniqueKeys + ")");
        }
    }
}
```

Dai então você poderia criar sua classe adicionando a propriedade `UniqueKey`.

```cs
public class User
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [UniqueKey]
    public string Login
}
```

Bom, assim você iria ter o atributo desejado validando no ***back-end*** e poderia criar um validação ***front-end*** consultando por AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

Na sua classe de dados, usando code first, você pode incluir o atributo "Key" acima da propriedade. Assim você indica que aquele campo é chave primária.

```cs
[Key, MaxLength(36), MinLength(36)]
public string CampoId { get; set; }
```