# Como declarar campos de chaves únicas com EntityFramework?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Uma coisa que muitos procuram mas que não há recurso disponível nas versões do `EntityFramework` até a **6** é o uso de ***chaves únicas*** (*unique keys*).

Inclusive surgiram usuários perguntando como criar tal controle e o incrível é que surgiram respostas indicando uma tal **`UniqueKey`** (??) 
**([Não permitir gravar cadastros duplicados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/14762/nao-permitir-gravar-cadastros-duplicados/14770#14770))**.
**Mas tal atributo não existe.**

**Como então controlar campos únicos?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Com a versão do `EntityFramework 6.1` veio um novo atributo, o `IndexAttribute`, e com ele é possível fazer esse tipo de declaração.

Exemplo:

```cs
public abstract class User
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    [Index("IX_User_Login", IsUnique = true)]
    public string Login { get; set; }
    ....
}
```

Um exemplo para índice/chave composta:

```cs
public abstract class User
{
    [Required]
    [Index("IX_User_Empresa", 1, IsUnique = true)]
    public int EmpresaId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    [Index("IX_User_Empresa", 2, IsUnique = true)]
    public string Login { get; set; }
    ....
}
```

**Referência: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583.aspx#IndexMulti)**