# Evitar salvar dados duplicados

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados, sql-server-2012

Em meu projeto tenho uma regra que é não salvar e não mostrar no *Grid* dados duplicados. Por exemplo, no sistema eu faço a leitura de um *XML* e salvo as informações das *tags* numa tabela do meu banco de dados para que essas informações seja mostradas em um *Grid*.

Só que toda vez que eu faço essa leitura, salva-se duas vezes os dados. Digo, se eu já li uma vez e já foi salvo, por exemplo, o nome 'João' nessa primeira leitura, se eu ler de novo o *XML*, o nome é salvo outra vez, e assim por diante, quantas vezes eu ler o *XML*.

Ai eu fiz uma lógica para que não mostrasse no *Grid* esses dados duplicados, que é essa:

```
if (Convert.ToString(GetValueOrDefault(elmCertidao.Element("nome_tag_1"))) == objeto.Propriedades["Coluna1"].Valor &&
                                    Convert.ToString(GetValueOrDefault(elmCertidao.Element("nome_tag_2"))) == objeto.Propriedades["Coluna2"].Valor &&
                                    Convert.ToString(GetValueOrDefault(elmCertidao.Element("nome_tag_3"))) == objeto.Propriedades["Coluna3"].Valor)
                                    continue;
```

Ou seja, se acaso houver dados nessas *tags* que já estejam no *Grid*, esses dados não são mostrados...

Até aqui beleza, mas acontece que os dados duplicados são salvos na tabela do banco, e não é isso que quero.

Quero que não mostre no *Grid* e nem salve dados duplicados.

[Essa pergunta aqui do SOpt](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/14762/n%C3%A3o-permitir-gravar-cadastros-duplicados) me de uma ideia do que fazer. Mas se eu colocar os campos como *Unique*, toda vez que eu ler o *XML*, e for verificado a inconsistência, vai dar erro no `SQL Server` falando que o dados já existe.

Existe alguma forma que eu faça essa verificação e não mostre erro, nem do `SQL Server` nem no `C#` ? Ou seja, salvando somente uma vez o dado ?

Comment: Qual a razão de ler mais de uma vez o *xml*?

Comment: Porque no `XML` podem conter uma tag que agrupe registros e ela se repete. Tipo uma NF-e(Aqui no Brasil). Ela tem uma tag que agrupa várias outras com registros, e essa tag que agrupa se repete várias vezes. E se caso eu precisar ler esse XML mais de uma vez, não quero salvar dados que já foram salvos.

Comment: Para evitar repetições utilize *Unique*. Antes de gravar faça uma leitura para verificar se o registo já existe ou então grave e faça o *catch* do erro. Se a possibilidade de haver repetições for grande use a primeira, caso seja pequena use a segunda.

Comment: Existe alguma forma de fazer isso via c# e sem mostrar erro ? Ou somente dessa forma ?

Comment: Ambas as formas é via C# e nenhuma mostra o erro.

Comment: Teria como colocar em uma resposta um exemplo ?

Comment: Você coloca os dados lidos do *xml* em alguma *collection* antes de gravar no banco?

Comment: Eu populo em um objeto que representa minha tabela no banco, mostro os dados no *Grid* e depois salvo no banco.

Comment: Esse objecto é uma `List<T>` onde T representa um registo da tabela?

Comment: Exatamente isso! Mas caso dê pra fazer de uma forma genérica, eu adapto a minha realidade.

Comment: Para lhe dar uma resposta necessito saber qual é a propriedade da sua classe que tem de ser única.

Comment: A Coluna1, Coluna2 e Coluna3 que estão lá no if. Ou seja, nome da pessoa, nome do pai e nome da mãe.

Comment: @ÉrikThiago, acho que você deveria tratar no momento de gravar. Uma simples rotina de verificação para saber se existe ou não no BD e aí soltar a rotina de gravação ou não. Conforme disse o ramaral.

Comment: @pnet você teria um exemplo de código que faz esse tipo de rotina?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se os dados lidos do *xml* são guardados numa `List<T>` antes de serem gravados no banco então elimine os duplicados da lista antes de gravar.

Uma forma simples de o fazer é usar o método [IQueryable.Distinct](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb348456%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Para que esse método possa distinguir o que é uma linha duplicada a sua classe terá de implementar a interface `IEquatable<T>`:

```
public class SuaClasse : IEquatable<SuaClasse>
{

    //Suas Propriedades
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string NomePai { get; set; }
    public string NomeMae { get; set; }
    ....
    .....
    //Seus Métodos
    ....
    ....

    //Implementação da Interface
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null) return false;
        SuaClasse objAs = obj as SuaClasse;
        if (objAs == null) return false;
        else return Equals(objAs);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Nome.GetHashCode() ^ NomePai.GetHashCode() ^ NomeMae.GetHashCode();
    }

    public bool Equals(SuaClasse other)
    {
        if(other == null)return false;
        return Nome.Equals(other.Nome) &&
               NomePai.Equals(other.NomePai) &&
               NomeMae.Equals(other.NomeMae);
    }
}
```

Para obter a lista sem duplicados use:

```
var ListaSemDuplicados = suaLista.Distinct().ToList();
```

Use `ListaSemDuplicados` para popular a *Grid* e para salvar no banco.

Comment: Bem, acho que o ramaral já respondeu.